# BCM 12 broken on RPI 3?

Tags: gpio, output

I'm having trouble using one of the GPIO pins. When trying to use BCM 12 (PIN 32 in BOARD mode, name: GPIO26) as an *output*, I get the warning:

```
RuntimeWarning: This channel is already in use, continuing anyway.
```

According to `gpio readall`, this pin is not in use and correctly set to out mode. Disabling the warnings didn't help.

This pin is supposed to be the trigger for an ultrasound sensor. My current system uses four of those, with triggers on other pins, and *three of them work perfectly*. The one on BCM 12, however, does not seem to switch the trigger on. The sensor works fine on other pins, yet I cannot switch to another pin, since all others are used for something else.

**Is it possible that BCM 12 is broken or being used by a service I have inadvertently activated?** I have double, triple and quadruple checked that it is not a wiring problem.

I am using Raspbian Stretch (the issue is the same on Jessie) on a Raspberry PI 3 B. All packages are up to date, including the firmware. There are four ultrasound sensors connected, a gyro-sensor, a gps-sensor, six ESCs (including motors), and all work fine with said ultrasound sensor being the only exception. For accessing the pins, I use PIGPIOD and python 3.

Can anyone help? Best regards Reto

Comment: I think that you are confusing pin names. Take a look here: https://pinout.xyz/ and edit your question.

Comment: Nope - issuing "gpio readall" provides a list of PINs and their respective names. Thus: BCM 12 = PIN 32 (invoked by setting the mode to BOARD) = GPIO 26. I really mean BCM 12, as is described by the link you provided.

Comment: No. The mode "BOARD" is something internal to the Python library you use. BCM 12 is pin 32 and is GPIO 12.
GPIO 26 is pin 37.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I solved the problem. It was a stupid mistake on my part.

I discovered that the external circuits, which I soldered myself, had one broken soldering joint. I have quite some electronics outside the Raspberry PI, and although my board worked perfectly before installing it, it broke while placing it into the casing. What a shameful mistake!

Sorry to have wasted everyone's time! And thank you for your trying to help me!

Best regards Reto

Answer (score 0):

The pigpio daemon does not issue that warning (warning, not error).

The message is issued by the RPi.GPIO Python module.  If I remember correctly RPi.GPIO tells you what do do if you don't want it to print that message.  For details on what the message means refer to the RPi.GPIO documentation.

Comment: The pigpio daemon indeed does not issue that warning. However, I am having trouble both using RPi.GPIO and pigpio. RPi.GPIO just gives me the warning I cited above, but does not explain the problem in greater detail.